# java.lang.RuntimeException:Illegal meta data value: the child service doesn't exist

Tags: android, chromium, samsung-galaxy

The crash occurs on Samsung Galaxy J6+, S7, S8+ and Note9. Android 8 and 9.

```
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-rc01'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:18.1.0'
```

Stack trace

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Illegal meta data value: the child service doesn't exist
   at nF0.a(nF0.java:3)
   at nF0.a(nF0.java:8)
   at org.chromium.content.browser.ChildProcessLauncherHelperImpl.a(ChildProcessLauncherHelperImpl.java:37)
   at mq2.run(mq2.java:5)
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
   at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:65)
```

Comment: Hi, Andriy. Did you fix it?

Comment: Hi,  Georgiy. No

Comment: hello @AndriyD. did you get any solution for it or any other way to fix it ?

Comment: @mihirahir no :(

Comment: Hi @AndriyD. Did you end up fixing it?

Comment: Hi @VamsiCalpakkam no